# What is the best way to use FDF with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, fdf

I need to build a PDF based on FDF.  I saw that Adobe has the FDF toolkit but saw others using ITextSharp.  I couldn't find anything on Adobe's toolkit and ASP.NET but saw examples on ITextSharp.  I wanted to know which I should use and if it is Adobe, does anyone have an example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use iTextSharp, I've used it before to handle PDF forms on the server. The reason why I didn't use Adobe FDF toolkit at the time was because Adobe is not supporting it anymore, and the licensing for it is quite restrictive since most of the solutions you'd develop would basically compete with one of the product they make.

For what I was trying to do (handling form responses), when I talk with one of the support guy at Adobe, they were recommending LifeCycle Enterprise, which was just too expensive for our budget.

Comment: I ended up using iTextSharp long ago but thank you for your answer.